# How to Mathematically Recover Sparse Signal (Least Squares with $ {L}_{1} $ Regularization - LASSO)?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, regularization, linear-approximation, sparse-matrices

I got this equation for signal recovery by using LASSO:

$$\alpha_y =\mathrm{argmin} \left(\| Y - D\alpha \|_2^2 + \lambda^* \|\alpha\|_1\right) $$

Here $D$ is a Dictionary, $Y$ is noisy data signal and $\alpha$ is sparse signal.

My question is that How can I mathematically recover $\alpha_y$ ?

Comment: this is basically a convex problem. There exists solvers to find the solution. ou may want to have a look at https://stanford.edu/~boyd/l1_ls/ and at the paper associated to this solver

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing

Comment: Yes, I know but I actually want to code this type model that is why I need to understand very closely. and also I have read some papers but there don't have the procedure to solve this. thanks @fonfonx

Comment: Try a gradient descent. If it doesn't work, try to understand how the paper solved the issue.

Comment: thanks @user1952009 , can u suggest some papers for me that may help me ?

Comment: @SudipDas: as you've correctly noticed, yours is a Lasso regression problem. Solving this can be done via classical methods (i.e no special treatment is warranted): LARS, coordinate descent (I recommend this is your problem is very very high-dimensional), FISTA, etc. BTW, are you aware of this work on dictionary-learning and sparse-coding https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/mairal_icml09.pdf ?

Comment: @dohmatob yes I know dictionary learning and also know the sparse coding using omp(here norm is L_0). But here it is not quite clear that how lars giving the sparse signal.

Comment: OK, then I'm lost. What's your question then ? Do you want to solve a Lasso model or do you want to know why such a model produces sparsity  ? Also, don't get confused between a model and a solver. LARS  is a solver; Lasso is a model. The latter produces sparsity;  it doesn't make sense to say the former produces / doesn't produce sparsity.

Comment: @dohmatob I actually want to solve the Lasso model from scratch by using Lars. Cause I have to code this lasso model to find sparse signal. Thanks,

Comment: @SudipDas, What are you after? An answer which describes how to solve this? If you do I can write something about solving it using few methods.

Comment: Yes you can write, @Royi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is using [Sub Gradient Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method) (Generalizes the Gradient Method).

A valid Sub Graidnet of the $ {L}_{1} $ Norm is given by the $ \operatorname{sign} \left( \cdot \right) $ function (Operatong element wise on vectors).

Hence:

$$ \partial \left\{ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \right\} = {A}^{T} \left( A x - b \right) + \lambda \operatorname{sign} \left( x \right) $$

So now we can iterate this fins the solution.
Since this is a Convex Optimization problem if the step size is small enough we can get as close as we want to the solution.

The are many more solvers to this problem (Which are much more efficient).
In most cases the fastest of them all is the Coordinate Descent.
You can find many solvers for this in my [$ {L}_{1} $ Norm Regularized Least Squares GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/Optimization/LsL1SolversAnalysis).

Comment: I'm not sure that in most cases the fastest method is coordinate decent. On similar problems where $A$ fits into RAM I think I've gotten better results using FISTA with a line search procedure. It might depend on the application.

Comment: I never added Line Search into FISTA (Or Accelerated Proximal Gradient). Could you share your experience? Is it even faster than ADMM? Usually, in my analysis (See code) the fastest (Number Iterations) was CD then ADMM. Note: For real life better test it compared to Wall Clock and not iterations (Maybe that's the difference between our findings).

Comment: @littleO, By the way, any thoughts on that - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762188 ? His intuition makes sense (Though clearly how he did it is wrong). I wonder if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much @Royi It is a perfect ans, great explanation, I want to keep in touch with you to learn more so, is there has any way ??